# Tengo problemas al momento de trazar la ruta

Tags: android-studio, google-maps

Buen dia, estoy tratando de trazar una ruta entre mi posicion actual hacia un destino, me sale una especie de error que dice: I/jsonRuta:: {
       "error_message" : "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to (IMAGEN)

Alguien que me puesa ayudar por favor

**Aquí en el metodo del **OnMapReady**, mediante el **setOnMyLocationChangeListener**** calculo mi posicion actual y tambien hago la peticion al web services del Api de Google Map.

```
 map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

                if (actualPosition){
                    latitudOrigen = location.getLatitude();
                    longitudOrigen = location.getLongitude();
                    actualPosition=false;

                    LatLng miPosicion = new LatLng(latitudOrigen,longitudOrigen);

                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(miPosicion).title("Aqui estoy yo"));

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(latitudOrigen,longitudOrigen))      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                            .zoom(15)

                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


                    String url ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" +
                            ""+latitudOrigen+","+longitudOrigen+"&destination=-2.1172431,-79.892731";

                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            try {
                                jso = new JSONObject(response);
                                trazarRuta(jso);
                                Log.i("jsonRuta: ",""+response);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    });

                    queue.add(stringRequest);
                }
            }
        });
```

**este es el metodo de trazar la ruta**, no me lanza un error rojo, es como un warning que dice:

```
private void trazarRuta(JSONObject jso) {

        JSONArray jRoutes,jLegs,jSteps;

       try {
            jRoutes = jso.getJSONArray("routes");
            for (int i=0; i<jRoutes.length();i++){

                jLegs = ((JSONObject)(jRoutes.get(i))).getJSONArray("legs");
                for (int j=0; j<jLegs.length();j++){
                    jSteps = ((JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");
                    for (int k = 0; k<jSteps.length();k++){


                        String polyline = ""+((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        Log.i("end",""+polyline);
                        List<LatLng> list = PolyUtil.decode(polyline);
                        map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(list).color(Color.RED).width(5));


**Funcion del OnMapReady**

@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        //permiso
       mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);//punto azul de tu ubicación actual
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        miUbicacionActual();
    }
```

**//Método para crear el marker**

```
  private void agregar_marker(double lat, double lng) {
        LatLng coordenadas = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate miUbicacion = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordenadas, 15);
        mMap.animateCamera(miUbicacion);
    }


**//Método que obtiene la lat y lng de mi posición actual**


   private void actualizaUbicacion(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            latitud = location.getLatitude();
            longitud = location.getLongitude();
            agregar_marker(latitud, longitud);
        }
    }
```

****//Objeto LocationListener, para estar pendiente a cualquier cambio de** localidad por el GPS**

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        actualizaUbicacion(location);
    }
```

**//Calcula mi posición actual mediante GPS**

```
void miUbicacionActual() {
    //permiso

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    actualizaUbicacion(location);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, locationListener);
    movMap();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);

}
```

**Nota: He quitado algunas llaves y los errorListener, para evitar menos codigo innecesario**
[image: IMAGEN]

Answer (score 0):

El error que indicas, "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs." significa que necesitas una clave que puedes generar de la siguiente manera:

- Entra a la página: https://code.google.com/apis/console/
- Debes iniciar sesión con una cuenta de Google. Si no tienes una deberás crearla. También debes darte de alta en Cloud Platform si no lo has hecho aceptando sus condiciones de servicio.
- Crea un nuevo proyecto y configúralo.
- En Biblioteca puedes seleccionar las APIs de las que quieres hacer uso.
- Busca un apartado llamado Credenciales y allí podas generar una clave de  API.

Para más información sobre generación de claves API visita su apartado en la [documentación de Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key). y un [tutorial](http://www.rubenalcaraz.es/pinakes/informatica/como-obtener-una-clave-api-para-google-maps/) en español con imágenes de cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Estimado gracias por responder, al parecer si tengo generada mi clave del Api en mi proyecto, lo que pasa que tengo 2 mapas en mi Navigation Drawer, en el que quiero trazar la ruta me sale ese error

Comment: ¿Solo con este mapa tienes problemas? ¿O con el otro también?

Comment: me imagino que si, porque en el otro puedo mover el marker y obtener la lat y log, pero en donde quiero trazar la ruta me sale ese error, sera que deberan ser 2 key Api, o solo basta con una para los 2 mapas

Comment: No creo que sea necesario tener otra key API. El mensaje que te aparece se muestra en Log.i("jsonRuta: ",""+response); en el primer código. El problema parece estar aquí `url ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" +""+latitudOrigen+","+longitudOrigen+"&destination=-2.1172431,-79.892731";` o en su defecto puede que en el método que usas para pedir respuesta (Request.Method). Sugiero que compartas el código del otro mapa que funciona bien, a ver cómo lo estás haciendo y solo el código de `setOnMyLocationChangeListener` que ya está aquí

Comment: en el otro mapa solamente tengo el marker en mi posicion actual y para moverlo, ya edite el codigo para Ud.lo pueda observar

Comment: Bueno, estaba esperando que el otro código cuente con una solicitud a los servidores de Google pero no la encontré. Por lo que me imagino que el problema es que al URL le está faltando un parámetro muy importante `"key=YOUR_API_KEY"`. Prueba este nuevo link: `"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + "" + latitudOrigen + "," + longitudOrigen + "&destination=-2.1172431,-79.892731&key=" + KEY`. Cabe mencionar que KEY es una variable que debes definir con el valor de tu key API.

Comment: Gracias por responder estimado, pero sigue saliendo lo mismo :(

Comment: Me parece extraño, estás ingresando bien tu key api? Yo lo pruebo y cuando ingreso la mía solo cambia de mensaje porque no pago ese servicio. Mira, pega el siguiente link en el navegador y añadele tu key api al final. Si lo hiciste bien no deberías recibir el mismo mensaje que en las imágenes que incluiste https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=10,-50&destination=-2.1172431,-79.892731&key=

Comment: Ya he intentando muchas cosas, la verdad no se que podra ser, por ultimo intente esto, me sale : error_message" : "The provided API key is invalid."

int KEY = R.string.google_maps_key;

String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + "" + latitudOrigen + "," + longitudOrigen +"&destination=-2.1172431, 79.892731&key="+KEY+"";

Comment: Bien, un error diferente, ese significa que la key api es inválida, por lo que el problema debe ser que hayas copiado mal la key api en R.string.google_maps_key. Comprueba que esté bien escrita, copiala de nuevo si es necesario.